# Alternative for FOR loops where FOR loop is really slow

Tags: pandas, numpy, for-loop, iterator, vectorization

[image: this is my sample dataset]

problem:
need to calculated deliverables(availability in the dataset).When a customer purchases some quantity of a product it will be subtracted from the inventory and shown as availability. This availability will be the new inventory. When the next customer comes and buys the same product if it is greater than the inventory, we don't subtract it and the inventory will be the same else if the quantity is less than inventory we subtract quantity from inventory .This activity must be done in a first in first out method.

what i tried:

i have sorted the data on date field(which is not in the sample)to achieve FIFO.Then created a master table with distinct products and their inventory, done a iteration which gave me the correct solution.
below is the code:

```
master_df = df[['product','inventory']].drop_duplicates()
master_df['free'] = df['inventory']
df['deliverable']=np.NaN
for i,row in df.iterrows():

    if i%1000==0:

        print(i)
    try:
        available = master_df[row['product']==master_df['product']]['free'].reset_index(drop=True).iloc[0]
        if available-row['quantity']>=0:
            df.at[i,'deliverable']=available-row['quantity']
            a = master_df.loc[row['product']==master_df['product']].reset_index()['index'].iloc[0]
            master_df.at[a,'free'] = available-row['quantity']
        else:
            df.at[i,'deliverable']=available
    except Exception as e:
         print(i)
         print(e)
print((df.columns))
df = df.fillna(0)
```

for this iteration to complete it takes **so much time** and this needed to be done in a **far lesser time**(because of the time limit in aws lambda) can you guys help me to optimise this code without the help of **for** loop.

Comment: Hello joe  welcome to stack overflow, it is good practice. To display you wanted result also, a sample df so we get the idea behind your solutions. That would be way more effective

Comment: First create a dictionary of product to stock level, then use it to check and update levels, then at the end use it to write the new levels back to the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `.groupby` with custom function:

```py
def fn(x):
    rv, current = [], x["inventory"].iat[0]
    for requested_quantity, inv in zip(x["quantity"], x["inventory"]):
        if requested_quantity <= inv:
            current = inv - requested_quantity
        rv.append(current)
    x["deliverable"] = rv


df.groupby("product", as_index=False).apply(fn)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   customer product  quantity  inventory  availability  deliverable
0         1       A       100        800           700        700.0
1         2       A      1000        700           700        700.0
2         3       A       700        700             0          0.0
3         4       A        50          0             0          0.0
4         5       B        20        100            80         80.0
5         6       B        50         80            30         30.0
6         7       B        40         30            30         30.0
7         8       B        30         30             0          0.0
```

Comment: thanks Kesely for your response and it is working. Need a clarification regarding the same question. We are subtracting quantity from inventory. What if the inventory value for a product is always same . Ie inventory for product A will be always 800 and B will be always 100 .in that case how to get the same output which you mentioned above?

Comment: @Joe Can you open a new question here on StackOverflow? Put example input as text (not as picture) and expected output. I'd try to look at it.

Comment: i have posted it as a new question. please look into it when you available.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73332149/go-through-every-rows-of-a-dataframe-without-iteration)